# Regex in python to extract elements and transform into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a raw text like this

[image]

and I'm using below method to extract values and save it in a dataframe.

```
out = (s.str.extractall(r'(?P<Object>Course Credits:|Total Hours)|(?P<Weight>\d+.00)')
        .groupby(level=0).first()
        )
```

Total Credits and its weight is available but I'm struglling to define a regex to detect just "Total Hours" and the number 75. I know its because of the extra "0" and no space after number 75, but I don't know how write the right expression.
In the end, I want something like this,

[image]

I copied the above code from stack overflow to get a differrent dataset, but in this case the strings are a little different.

Comment: what if you just write `(?P<Weight>\d+)`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
s.str.extractall(r'(?P<Object>Course Credits|Total Hours\s)(?::?\s*?)(?P<Weight>[\d.]+)')
```

Comment: Just tried using this, but it still doesn't give me "Total Hours" and 75. In fact, it just gives me Course Credits and its value.

Comment: Consider providing an explanation of this regex